# CSS: Aligning elements in DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have trouble aligning some elements in a div correctly.

[image]

This is what I have so far. I want my Bootstrap slider to be aligned vertically so that the bottom of the slide matches the bottom of the yellow input text on the right.

This is my CSS:

```
.filter {
    display: inline;
    clear: both !important;
}

.filter h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    line-height: 20px !important;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    clear:both;
}

.filter_slider {
    width:300px !important;
    float: left !important;
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
}

.filter_text {
    background: #ffffcc !important;
    width: 80px !important;
    float: right !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
    <div class="filter">
        <h1>Price</h1>
        <input id="filter_slider_price" class="filter_slider" value="" data-slider-min="-20" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="-14" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="hide">
        <input type="text" id="filter_text_price" class="filter_text" readonly>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#filter_slider_price').slider().on('slide', function(ev) { $('#filter_text_price').val(ev.value); });
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class="filter">
        <h1>Volume</h1>
        <input id="filter_slider_volume" class="filter_slider" value="" data-slider-min="-20" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="-14" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="hide">
        <input type="text" id="filter_text_volume" class="filter_text" readonly>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#filter_slider_volume').slider().on('slide', function(ev) { $('#filter_text_volume').val(ev.value); });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you also provide a sample of the HTML that you are using? that would be helpful in determining what the appropriate CSS may be.

Comment: Added html to OP. Also, looking to push the input text field right next to the slider. Tried float left on both but that didnt work.

Comment: Why do you have !important on everything? This is very bad practice because they cannot be overridden by later classes defying the purpose of cascading style sheets. Also the fact that the containers are floating means they are not in the flow and you will have a hard time positioning them vertically. Look up display:inline-block

Comment: `!important` is good for certain situations. However it is completely un-necessary for every element. But if this is something that is required within your css in order for it to function properly then you should look into making some more unique classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Paceaux/Dv3r3/

I assumed the following semantic HTML, including the HTML5 `range` attribute and `<ouptut>` element:

```
<form class="form_filter">
<fieldset class="filter">
  <label for="range1" class="filter_label">price</label>
  <input type="range" id="range1" class="filter_slider"/>
  <output class="filter_text">
    10
  </output>
```

and I was able to get a desirable result similar to your screenshot by using `position:relative` on the `.filter_label` and some padding shenanigans on the `.filter_text`.

Because I don't have any context for using `!important`, I removed it from the CSS:

```
.form_filter{
  width: 420px;
}
.filter {
  display: block;
}
.filter_label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.filter_slider {
  width:300px;
}
.filter_text {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  top:-55px;
  float:right;
  padding-top:40px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #ffffcc;
}
```